# How to output and add in hexadecimal in assembly language

Tags: assembly, hex, addition

I have a program I'm working on for homework, and I have everything finished except this simple part.
I need to get two hexadecimal numbers from ReadInt, store them in a variable, and then add the two together and output the answer as hexadecimal.

How can I do this?
This isn't my full code, but the part relating to this question looks like this.

```
.data
var1 DWORD ?
var2 DWORD ?
var3 DWORD ?
.code
message PROC
mov edx, 0
mov edx, OFFSET msg1
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov var1, eax
mov edx, OFFSET msg2
call WriteString
call ReadInt
mov var2, eax
mov eax, var1
mov ebx, var2
add eax,ebx
mov var3,eax
mov edx, OFFSET msg3
call WriteString
mov eax, var3
call WriteInt
call crlf
ret
message ENDP
```

Comment: Look at what your fundamental output operation can do (does it output an ASCII character? A string? Or what?). Then you have to convert your number to that. If it's an ASCII character at a time, then you need to take your number and convert each nibble (4 bits) into an ASCII character by adding `'0'` if it's between 0-9, or adding `'A' - Ah` if it's between `A` and `F`.

Comment: A number in a computer is only "truly" binary, but the base you think of it in is really irrelevant most of the time, a number is a number, when you input or output numbers what matters is how the input or output function handles ASCII conversions, if the function expects a number as input and outputs a string conversion, the function determines if the string is in binary, hex, decimal, e.t.c. If the function expects a string and converts it to a number, it's up to the function what strings of number bases it understands and can convert to binary.